# View Update when Function Result changes | SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm stuck with a problem. I have a SwiftUI View, which has a `ForEach(){}` loop in it. Each object in this loop gets some Number from a external function, like this:

```
func returnRightNum(_ item: typeOfElements) -> Int {
        // Make some calculation
        var someExampleNum = 5
        return someExampleNum
    }

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(myArray){ element in
            Text("\(returnRightNum(element))")
        }
    }
```

So far everything is working great, now my problem: The `returnRightNum` function returns a  value, depending on the state of some other values. That means the result of `returnRightNum` should change, whenever these values change. But this function only gets called once, on render of the View. Let my show you some code.

```
var otherValue1: Bool = false
    var otherValue2: Bool = false
    var otherValue3: Bool = false    

    func returnRightNum(_ item: typeOfElements) -> Int {
        // Make some calculation, depending on otherValue1, otherValue2 and otherValue3.

        var someExampleNum = 5

        // Change the Result
        if otherValue2 && otherValue3 {
            someExampleNum = 3
        } else if otherValue1 {
            someExampleNum = 2
        } else {
            someExampleNum = 1
        }

        return someExampleNum
    }

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(myArray){ element in
            Text("\(returnRightNum(element))")
        }
    }
```

I know, you could solve this by using a computed property, like this:

```
var computedValue: Int {
            // Make some calculation, depending on otherValue1, otherValue2 and otherValue3.
    
            var someExampleNum = 5
    
            // Change the Result
            if otherValue2 && otherValue3 {
                someExampleNum = 3
            } else if otherValue1 {
                someExampleNum = 2
            } else {
                someExampleNum = 1
            }
    
            return someExampleNum
        }
```

But this wouldn't work for me, because `someExampleNum` is dependent on a the input, and you can't give a computed property a special input...

What I would need is a function, that triggers a View Update like a `@State`, when the value of it changes.

Is there any way to achieve that, or do you got an other idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If updates to `otherValue1`, `otherValue2` and `otherValue3` mean that your view should be re-rendered, then those variables should be `@State` or `@Binding` properties. That will trigger a re-render should the values change.